# how to dynamically allocate size of string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays, stringtokenizer

hello I am beginner to work with java. I have following code, where I wanted to initialize the string array word[] dynamically consisting of size of total no. of tokens in all documents [] array.
how should I do that?

```
String []result = {"Shipment of Gold damaged in fire","Delivery of silver arrived in silver truck","shipment of Gold arrived in Truck"};
String []documents = new String[result.length];
    for (int  k =0; k<result.length; ++k){ 
        documents[k] = result[k].toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("document["+k+"] :" + documents[k]);
    }
    /*step 2: Tokenize all documents  and create vocabulary from it*/
    int i=0; 
    String [] word = new String [30]; // how to do dynamic allocation here
    int no_of_tokens=0;

    for(String document:documents){
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(document," ");
        System.out.print("tokens in document"+ i +":"+ st.countTokens()+"\n");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word[no_of_tokens]=st.nextToken();
            System.out.print(word[no_of_tokens] + "\n");
            no_of_tokens++;
        }
        i++; 
    }
```

Comment: ArrayList? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list

Comment: The Java ArrayList grows automatically. You don't have to worry about resizing it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: @NicolásCarlo: This must be a homework. Usually, they come with the constraints to use such low level classes and techniques. Just compare the amount of code with the amount of work that it's doing.

Comment: The Javadoc for `StringTokenizer` says "... StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. ..." so I think you should avoid it.  And if you are a student and your teacher has instructed you to use it, then show him/her the Javadoc.  You should be using `split` for something like this, and that automatically gives you an array of the right size.

Comment: thank you so much every one for the help..

Comment: @DavidWallace : yes I am a student but not studied java as formal subject in class. learning it through tutorials videos and such forums. would you please suggest any tutorials from which I can learn java thoroughly.?

Comment: I haven't found anything better than the online Java tutorials on the Oracle site.  You might also like to look for the author Bruce Eckel - you may be able to find an online copy of one of his excellent books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a `List` such as `ArrayList`, or use `String.split()` instead of `StringTokenizer`, it will return a `String[]`.

Comment: Using `split()` is the only reasonable answer to this question.  +1 for being the only person to mention it so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a static array.  You can't resize a static array, but you can create a new, bigger, static array and then copy the initial contents over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of the `List` interface, like [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for this case. It will resize automatically when it almost fills so you don't have to worry about figuring the right initial size.

You use it like this:

```
....
/*step 2: Tokenize all documents  and create vocabulary from it*/
int i=0; 
List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>(); // how to do dynamic allocation here
int no_of_tokens=0;

....

while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.add(st.nextToken());
    System.out.print(word.get(no_of_tokens) + "\n");
    no_of_tokens++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ArrayList<String>` or `LinkedList<String>`. The two differ in the overhead for `add`ing elements (LinkedList is fast, ArrayList is slow) and `get`ting elements via get(i) (LinkedList is slow, ArrayList is fast).

Comment: Actually `ArrayList` wins even when adding. Especially if you estimate the size properly when creating it (to minimize the resizes).