# putting multiple objects into a arraylist and draw them

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel

I have just learned to use arraylist so be nice :P .

I wonder how i can put a few objects (like  a `circle` or a `square`) into the `arraylist` and draw them out on a `jpanel` so all of them stay. I know how to draw one thing but i'm trying to make a game and would like to have multiple things drawn at the same time.

All answers appreciated!

Comment: "I have just learned to use arraylist so be nice :P"...sigh. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list

Comment: Which part are you having table with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont femiliar with JPanel and swing but a bsic algorithm will be:

1. add all the wanted objects to arraylist (or an other data stracture)
2. Start Loop
3. for every item on the data stracture - item.Draw
4. update all locations
5. return to loop start