# How to insert item in array?

Tags: java

My code array. How to insert item in array?

```
int listElemCount = jCBWorkerMen.getItemCount();
Object[] selectionValues = null;
for (int i = 0; i < listElemCount; i++) {
        selectionValues[i]  =  (Object[]) jCBWorkerMen.getItemAt(i);
        System.out.println(selectionValues);
     }
String initialSelection = "Dogs";
Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What are your favorite   animals?", "Zoo Quiz", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, selectionValues,  initialSelection);
System.out.println(selection);
```

Comment: Use a `List`, like `ArrayList`, assuming you mean you want to change the length of the array...

Comment: If you want to insert (add, change the length of, etc.) an array, use a `List<E>`, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list

Comment: also, what is the type of `jCBWorkerMen` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(10);

        Object[] selectionValues = new Object[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
            selectionValues[i] = list.get(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < selectionValues.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(selectionValues[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect, this

> ```
> int listElemCount = jCBWorkerMen.getItemCount();
> Object[] selectionValues = null;
> for (int i = 0; i < listElemCount; i++) {
>    selectionValues[i]  =  (Object[]) jCBWorkerMen.getItemAt(i);
>    System.out.println(selectionValues);
> }
> ```

needs to start by initializing the array. Also, you probably shouldn't print the array until you finish initializing it. Finally, you need to use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) because Java arrays don't override `toString()`. So something like,

```
int listElemCount = jCBWorkerMen.getItemCount();
Object[] selectionValues = new Object[listElemCount];
for (int i = 0; i < listElemCount; i++) {
    selectionValues[i] = jCBWorkerMen.getItemAt(i);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectionValues));
```

Answer (score 0):

The change code should be like as below

```
int listElemCount = jCBWorkerMen.getItemCount();
    Object[] selectionValues = new Object[listElemCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < listElemCount; i++) {
            selectionValues[i]  = jCBWorkerMen.getItemAt(i);
            //System.out.println(selectionValues);
         }
   //to view the all the items in the array
   for (int i = 0; i < listElemCount; i++) {            
            System.out.println(selectionValues[i]);
   }
    String initialSelection = "Dogs";
    Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What are your favorite   animals?", "Zoo Quiz", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, selectionValues,  initialSelection);
    System.out.println(selection);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I liked your answer!