# How to declare a dynamic array of String?

Tags: java

I want to declare an `array` of `String` whose `dimension` is not known. How to declare and initialize it ?

Comment: What language are you using for this?

Comment: the language is android

Comment: an array has a fixed size and is not dynamic.  The closest thing is to use a `List` instead.

Comment: @pheromix android is the platform, not the language. Java is the official language used for android but there are other ways such as using Apache Cordova™.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, arrays have fixed size and the length cannot be changed once they are declared.

But as suggested by others, use arraylist. Although the syntax is slightly different, array and arraylist work the same way.

[Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2697225/3886922)

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

This is a dynamic list of elements `<String>`

Comment: Not technically an array.