# Trying to convert program from array to array list java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two classes. At the moment, you can save 99 entries to a .txt file. Obviously I want to expand upon this. It would be good if the following from ExamGradesGUI were an arraylist rather than an array:

```
    String[] firstName = new String[99];
    String[] lastName = new String[99];
    String[] subjectUnit = new String[99];
    double[] examMark = new double[99];
```

I managed to start off by declaring the array as below (for firstName):

```
ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then, I was not sure how to make it work with my get and set methods as obviously they are still in array form. If someone could help I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: You should always code to the interface. Don't declare variables of concrete collection types. Instead of `ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();` you need to do `List<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: `Obviously I want to expand upon this, obviously they are still in array form`, you are in for a surprise. The solution is obvious as well.

Comment: You can use the `get(index)` resp. `set(index, element)` methods on the list. But you need to create the list as `List<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>(99);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use an array list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list)

Comment: @malfunctioning in the getText() field

firstName[i] = firstNameTxt.getText();

the expression must be an array type but is resolved to Array<String>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be more OOP to have :

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

Class Student{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String subjectUnit;
    private double examMark ;
    // Generate getters and setters and constructor
```

}

```
// So the code to create a new Student in getText(): 
 Student newStudent = new Student ( 
       firstNameTxt.getText() ,
       lastNameTxt.getText(), 
    subjectUnitTxt.getItemAt(subjectUnitTxt.getSelectedIndex()), 
    Double.parseDouble(examMarkTxt.getText()) );

// add the newStudent to the list
students.add( newStudent );
```

Comment: This is good, but how would it work with: public ExamGradesGUI readRecords(){ in the ExamGrades program?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [List#add(int index,E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

```
void add(int index,
       E element)
```

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list
>   (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position
>   (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
>   indices).

with this method you can replace

```
firstName[i] = firstNameTxt.getText();
```

this with

```
firstName.add(i,firstNameTxt.getText());
```

---

**Update**

you can replace

```
public void addRecords(String[] first, String[] last, String[] subject, double[] mark)
```

with

```
  public void addRecords(List<String> first,List<String> last, List<String> subject,List<double> mark) {
this.firstNameList=first;
this.lastNameList=last;
this.subjectList=subject;
this.marksList=mark;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now for the line: 

   save.addRecords(firstName, lastName, subjectUnit, examMark);

"The method addRecords(String[], String[], String[], double[]) in the type ExamGrades is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>, String[], String[], double[])"

What would I change:

public void addRecords(String[] first, String[] last, String[] subject, double[] mark)

to?

Comment: It won't work for this line: gui.firstName[i] = input.next(); the type of the expression must be an array type but it is resolved to a list<string>. It says dimensions are expected after this token for the <double> one as well

Comment: We are not here to write code for you , this site is just for guiding you on correct path ,  so that you can resolve it on your own . You get the idea now just go ahead and try to fix it yourself !! 
**P.S. : Don't just copy and paste the Code**