# move object1 of an array to a new object(object2) and remove the object 1 from array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an Array of objects.

```
Filter[] filter = [{a:1,b:2},{c,3,d:4}]
```

I want to take out specific object suppose `{a:1,b:2}`
to other object 
then store in rsFilter = {a:1,b:2}
and remove {a:1,b:2} from array

I tried hard. I am not able to get proper logic.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` instead of array. It makes things simpler.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java...

Comment: can you share some code you have tried please ....

Comment: Hi,
I tried using the below:
List<Filter> list = Arrays.asList(filter);
  Filter rateSheetFilter = list.remove(0); (currently it is index is 0,i will update it with correct index once it works)
  Filter[] ar = new Filter[2];
  ar[0]=list.toArray(); (what if i have only 1 object and it is removed from my logic. that time will the list.toArry will work?)
  ar[1]=rateSheetFilter;
  return ar;

I have a doubt if

Comment: @prashanth, please put that information by editing the question. Also, when using `Arrays.asList()` you get a **fixed sized list** which means you cannot add or remove items from it.

Answer (score 0):

use ArrayList for the same pupose.

```
List<Filter> l=new ArrayList<Filter>()
```

now create the objects of your Filter.
add like `l.add()`
remove like `l.remove()`

also see: [how to use an array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2697182/4793343)