# How do I use the HeapSort Method after the user has already created the Heap?

Tags: java, algorithm, heapsort, binary-heap

Hey guys so i'm working on a lab assignment for my programming class and we have to create a heap where the user enters integers into an array then displays it, then we are suppose to use those same values and use HeapSort well the first part was fairly easy, i'm having trouble trying to call the HeapSort method in order to sort the array everytime i do i come up with this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>  at
>   HeapApp.heapSort(HeapApp.java:11)
>  at
>   HeapApp.main(HeapApp.java:88)

The error specifically points out

```
int count = hp.length;
```

and

```
HeapApp.heapSort(HP);
```

please help! Its one of my last assignments for this class!

Heap Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private  ArrayList<T> items;


public Heap() {
    items = new ArrayList<T>();
}

private void siftUp() {
    int k = items.size() - 1;
    while (k > 0) {
        int p = (k-1)/2;
        T item = items.get(k);
        T parent = items.get(p);
        if (item.compareTo(parent) > 0) {
            // swap
            items.set(k, parent);
            items.set(p, item);

            // move up one level
            k = p;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void insert(T item) {
    items.add(item);
    siftUp();
}

private void siftDown() {
    int k = 0;
    int l = 2*k+1;
    while (l < items.size()) {
        int max=l, r=l+1;
        if (r < items.size()) { // there is a right child
            if (items.get(r).compareTo(items.get(l)) > 0) {
                max++;
            }
        }
        if (items.get(k).compareTo(items.get(max)) < 0) {
                // switch
                T temp = items.get(k);
                items.set(k, items.get(max));
                items.set(max, temp);
                k = max;
                l = 2*k+1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public T delete() 
throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (items.size() == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    if (items.size() == 1) {
        return items.remove(0);
    }
    T hold = items.get(0);
    items.set(0, items.remove(items.size()-1));
    siftDown();
    return hold;
}

public int size() {
    return items.size();
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return items.isEmpty();

}

public String toString() {
    return items.toString();
}


}

import java.util.Scanner;


public class HeapApp {



/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Heap<Integer> hp = new Heap<Integer>();


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    HeapApp HP = new HeapApp();
    System.out.print("Enter next int, 'done' to stop: ");
    String line = sc.next();

    while (!line.equals("done")) {
        hp.insert(Integer.parseInt(line));
        System.out.println(hp);
        System.out.print("Enter next int, 'done' to stop: ");
        line = sc.next();
    }

    while (hp.isEmpty()) {
        //int max = hp.delete();
        System.out.println(hp);
    }


    System.out.println(hp);
    HP.heapSort(HP);
    System.out.println("After sorting " + hp);

 }




private static int [] hp;



public static void heapSort(HeapApp HP){
        int count = hp.length;

        //first place a in max-heap order
        heapify(hp, count);

        int end = count - 1;
        while(end > 0){
            //swap the root(maximum value) of the heap with the
            //last element of the heap
            int tmp = hp[end];
            hp[end] = hp[0];
            hp[0] = tmp;
            //put the heap back in max-heap order
            siftDown(hp, 0, end - 1);
            //decrement the size of the heap so that the previous
            //max value will stay in its proper place
            end--;
        }
    }

    public static void heapify(int[] hp, int count){
        //start is assigned the index in a of the last parent node
        int start = (count - 2) / 2; //binary heap

        while(start >= 0){
            //sift down the node at index start to the proper place
            //such that all nodes below the start index are in heap
            //order
            siftDown(hp, start, count - 1);
            start--;
        }
        //after sifting down the root all nodes/elements are in heap order
    }

    public static void siftDown(int[] hp, int start, int end){
        //end represents the limit of how far down the heap to sift
        int root = start;

        while((root * 2 + 1) <= end){      //While the root has at least one child
            int child = root * 2 + 1;           //root*2+1 points to the left child
            //if the child has a sibling and the child's value is less than its sibling's...
            if(child + 1 <= end && hp[child] < hp[child + 1])
                child = child + 1;           //... then point to the right child instead
            if(hp[root] < hp[child]){     //out of max-heap order
                int tmp = hp[root];
                hp[root] = hp[child];
                hp[child] = tmp;
                root = child;                //repeat to continue sifting down the child now
            }else
                return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting by selecting the code and clicking on the code button. Also explain which row is the one that the exception comes from.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static int [] hp; is null
```

Verify have you initialized the hp array before access  this line

```
   int count = hp.length;
```

Please refer the links

[How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)

[How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

If you want use dynamic array then please refer here

[how to use an array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean please

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example program for heap sort. The example takes int [] as input for heap sorting. Call the doHeapSort method and pass int []

```
public static void doHeapSort(int [] inputArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        keepMaxHeapFindingParentElement(i, inputArray);
    }
    sortAndMaintainHeap(inputArray, inputArray.length - 1);
}


private static void sortAndMaintainHeap(int [] inputArray, int lastElementIndex)
{
    if(lastElementIndex <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    swap(inputArray, 0, lastElementIndex);
    lastElementIndex--;
    keepMaxHeapFindingChildElement(inputArray, 0, lastElementIndex);
    sortAndMaintainHeap(inputArray, lastElementIndex);
}

private static void keepMaxHeapFindingChildElement(int [] inputHeap, int currentElementIndex, int lastElementIndex)
{
    if(currentElementIndex >= lastElementIndex)
    {
        //no more child node
        return;
    }
    int child1Index = 2*currentElementIndex + 1;
    int child2Index = 2*currentElementIndex + 2;
    int childIndex = 0;
    if(child2Index <= lastElementIndex)
    {
        childIndex = inputHeap[child1Index] > inputHeap[child2Index] ? child1Index : child2Index;
    }
    else if(child1Index <= lastElementIndex)
    {
        childIndex = child1Index;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    if(inputHeap[currentElementIndex] < inputHeap[childIndex])
    {
        swap(inputHeap, currentElementIndex, childIndex);
        keepMaxHeapFindingChildElement(inputHeap, childIndex, lastElementIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

private static void keepMaxHeapFindingParentElement(int elementIndex, int [] inputHeap)
{
    if(elementIndex == 0)
    {
        // no more parent node
        return;
    }
    int parentElementIndex = (elementIndex - 1)/2;
    if(inputHeap[elementIndex] > inputHeap[parentElementIndex])
    {
        //swap child and parent
        swap(inputHeap, elementIndex, parentElementIndex);
        keepMaxHeapFindingParentElement(parentElementIndex, inputHeap);
    }
}
```