# Add items to List in Java

Tags: java

I'm adding items to a List but the previous item always gets overwritten by later after the iteration.

```
List<CartPojo> cartLists = new ArrayList<CartPojo>();
CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo();

for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
   cartItem.setItemName("name_"+k);
   cartLists.add(cartItem);
}

model.addAttribute("cartLists", cartLists);
```

**This gives the output:** name_1, name_1

**Expected output:** name_0, name_1

Comment: You're always adding the same object. Put CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo(); into the for loop.

Comment: Create the new item inside the loop, not outside. Otherwise you're just adding the same item over and over.

Comment: You can get more examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486240/add-items-to-list-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're operating on the same instance throughout the iterations, rather you should instantiate the object inside the loop i.e:

```
for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
   CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo();
   cartItem.setItemName("name_"+k);
   cartLists.add(cartItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are keep modifying the same object each time. You need to create Object inside the loop.

```
for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
   CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo();
   cartItem.setItemName("name_"+k);
   cartLists.add(cartItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring new "CartPojo" instances, so every time you do something on cartItem, it is the same object every time that is being manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

> Just put Cartpojo cartItem=new CartPojo(); inside the for loop

List cartLists = new ArrayList();

for(int k=0; k<2; k++){

CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo();

cartItem.setItemName("name_"+k);

cartLists.add(cartItem);

}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create object every time inside the loop

```
List<CartPojo> cartLists = new ArrayList<CartPojo>();


for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
   CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo();
   cartItem.setItemName("name_"+k);
   cartLists.add(cartItem);
}

model.addAttribute("cartLists", cartLists);
```

Peace

Answer (score 0):

You use the same object in all iterations.
You should create an instance (with the `new` operator) at each time you want to create a `CartPojo` object.

Besides you should provide a constructor in `CartPojo` :

```
for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
    CartPojo cartItem = new CartPojo("name_"+k);
    cartLists.add(cartItem);
}
```

It makes the code more clear.