# Repeat the same variable for different users

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I was wondering if I can use the same variable for different users added in the atm interface. In order for the code not to get too messy. If I can just store different people's data in to one variable

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ATM {

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Bank theBank = new Bank("B-Cash");

        //add a user
        User aUser = theBank.addUser("Carl", "Bustamante", "0605");
        User bUser = theBank.addUser("Justin", "Borns", "3213");

        Account newAccount = new Account("Checking", aUser, theBank);
        aUser.addAccount(newAccount);
        theBank.addAccount(newAccount);

        Account newAccount1 = new Account("Checking", bUser, theBank);
        bUser.addAccount(newAccount);
        theBank.addAccount(newAccount);


    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is at best confusing.

Comment: ummm I was aiming to store all data of different users in a single variable

Comment: You could store them in a `List`

Comment: Ummm how could I do that can you show me how? I'm kinda new to this stuff sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can just store different people's data in to one variable

You cannot reference multiple object(Users) to a single object variable.

```
User user = new User();
```

In this statement, the `user` object variable stores a reference to a new `User` object.

If you would like to store multiple `Users` objects, try:

```
class Bank {
    List<String> users;

    public List<String> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<String> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

[How to use an array list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697182/how-to-use-an-array-list-in-java/2697230)

Comment: I Have a class called bank that uses the variable users for an array list of a class called account which list all of the accounts present. I am confused im going to be honest i can post the other class if there is need to

Comment: Edit your post with more details please.