# Should I use an Iterator or a forloop to iterate?

Tags: java, list, loops, dictionary, iterator

I don't like the idea of having to call `hasNext()` and `next()`, and seeing how I would need a loop to call those anyways, I don't really see much point in using the iterators given to us in Lists and Maps.

Is it only if you need to pull one this from the list? Or, if you're taking one item from the list, and having to do that for an unmeasured amount of time? I couldn't find this on Google or Stack, please help me out.

I'm not talking about an enhanced for-loop specifically (for-each loop).

I also understand that foreach loops excel in performance, but this is more of a 'why does it exist' question

EDIT: Realized I was talking about collections alone and not arrays aswel. `Foreach` loops don't have limitations in this situation.

Comment: You would have to use it when you want to remove while iterating -- which you cannot do with a foreach loop. Note that "internally" a foreach loop uses an iterator (see the javadoc for `Iterable`).

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) if(list.get(i).equals("example") list.remove(i);`
Wouldn't that work?

Comment: It would, yes... Matter of choice I guess ;) But hat you use here is not a foreach loop, it is a third solution :p

Comment: @VinceEmigh  `foreach` has performance advantages over `for`, because iterator-based access is faster than index-based access in many cases. See my answer.

Comment: No, modifying the list during a for loop would not work.  Let's say you have a list (a,b,c,d).  If you remove a the index is still incremented and with the modified list (b,c,d) the next iteration through the loop will return c and skip over b.

Comment: @VinceEmigh If you change it to `for(int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)` then your code would work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `foreach` is equivalent to an iterator--it's syntactic sugar for the same thing. So you should always choose `foreach` over iterator whenever you can, simply because it's convenient and results in more concise code.

I've written about this in another answer: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110482/uses-and-syntax-for-for-each-loop-in-java/22110517#22110517*

As stated by @RonnyShapiro, there are situations where you need to use an iterator, but in many cases a `foreach` should suffice. Note that a `foreach` is *not* a normal `for` loop. The normal `for` loop is needed when access to the index is required. Although you could manually create a separate index int-variable with `foreach` it is not ideal, from a [variable-scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) point of view.

Here's some more information: *[Which is more efficient, a for-each loop, or an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator)*

When accessing collections, a `foreach` is [significantly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879255/traditional-for-loop-vs-iterator-in-java) than the basic `for` loop's array access. When accessing arrays, however--at least with primitive and wrapper-arrays--access via indexes is *way* faster. See below.

---

Indexes are 23-***40*** percent faster than iterators when accessing `int` or `Integer` arrays. Here is the output from the below testing class, which sums the numbers in a 100-element primitive-int array (A is iterator, B is index):

```
[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 358,597,622 nanoseconds
Test B: 269,167,681 nanoseconds
B faster by 89,429,941 nanoseconds (24.438799231635727% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 377,461,823 nanoseconds
Test B: 278,694,271 nanoseconds
B faster by 98,767,552 nanoseconds (25.666236154695838% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 288,953,495 nanoseconds
Test B: 207,050,523 nanoseconds
B faster by 81,902,972 nanoseconds (27.844689860906513% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 375,373,765 nanoseconds
Test B: 283,813,875 nanoseconds
B faster by 91,559,890 nanoseconds (23.891659337194227% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 375,790,818 nanoseconds
Test B: 220,770,915 nanoseconds
B faster by 155,019,903 nanoseconds (40.75164734599769% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 326,373,762 nanoseconds
Test B: 202,555,566 nanoseconds
B faster by 123,818,196 nanoseconds (37.437545972215744% faster)
```

The full testing class:

```
   import  java.text.NumberFormat;
   import  java.util.Locale;
/**
   <P>{@code java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000}</P>

   @see  <CODE><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java</A></CODE>
 **/
public class TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray  {
   public static final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
   public static final void main(String[] tryCount_inParamIdx0)  {
      int testCount;
      //Get try-count from command-line parameter
         try  {
            testCount = Integer.parseInt(tryCount_inParamIdx0[0]);
         }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException x)  {
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Missing or invalid command line parameter: The number of testCount for each test. " + x);
         }

      //Test proper...START
         int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100};

         long lStart = System.nanoTime();
            for(int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)  {
               testIterator(intArray);
            }
         long lADuration = outputGetNanoDuration("A", lStart);

         lStart = System.nanoTime();
            for(int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)  {
               testFor(intArray);
            }
         long lBDuration = outputGetNanoDuration("B", lStart);

         outputGetABTestNanoDifference(lADuration, lBDuration, "A", "B");
   }
      private static final void testIterator(int[] int_array)  {
         int total = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < int_array.length; i++)  {
            total += int_array[i];
         }
      }
      private static final void testFor(int[] int_array)  {
         int total = 0;
         for(int i : int_array)  {
            total += i;
         }
      }
      //Test proper...END

//Timer testing utilities...START
   public static final long outputGetNanoDuration(String s_testName, long l_nanoStart)  {
      long lDuration = System.nanoTime() - l_nanoStart;
      System.out.println("Test " + s_testName + ": " + nf.format(lDuration) + " nanoseconds");
      return  lDuration;
   }

   public static final long outputGetABTestNanoDifference(long l_aDuration, long l_bDuration, String s_aTestName, String s_bTestName)  {
      long lDiff = -1;
      double dPct = -1.0;
      String sFaster = null;
      if(l_aDuration > l_bDuration)  {
         lDiff = l_aDuration - l_bDuration;
         dPct = 100.00 - (l_bDuration * 100.0 / l_aDuration + 0.5);
         sFaster = "B";
      }  else  {
         lDiff = l_bDuration - l_aDuration;
         dPct = 100.00 - (l_aDuration * 100.0 / l_bDuration + 0.5);
         sFaster = "A";
      }
      System.out.println(sFaster + " faster by " + nf.format(lDiff) + " nanoseconds (" + dPct + "% faster)");
      return  lDiff;
   }
//Timer testing utilities...END
}
```

I also ran this for an `Integer` array, and indexes are still the clear winner, but only between 18 and 25 percent faster.

For a `List` of `Integers`, however, iterators are faster. Just change the int-array in the above code to

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100});
```

and make the necssary changes to the test-function (`int[]` to `List<Integer>`, `length` to `size()`, etc)

```
[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 3,429,929,976 nanoseconds
Test B: 5,262,782,488 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,832,852,512 nanoseconds (34.326681820485675% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 2,907,391,427 nanoseconds
Test B: 3,957,718,459 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,050,327,032 nanoseconds (26.038700083921256% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 2,566,004,688 nanoseconds
Test B: 4,221,746,521 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,655,741,833 nanoseconds (38.71935684115413% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 2,770,945,276 nanoseconds
Test B: 3,829,077,158 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,058,131,882 nanoseconds (27.134122749113843% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 3,467,474,055 nanoseconds
Test B: 5,183,149,104 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,715,675,049 nanoseconds (32.60101667104192% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntList 1000000
Test A: 3,439,983,933 nanoseconds
Test B: 3,509,530,312 nanoseconds
A faster by 69,546,379 nanoseconds (1.4816434912159906% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntList 1000000
Test A: 3,451,101,466 nanoseconds
Test B: 5,057,979,210 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,606,877,744 nanoseconds (31.269164666060377% faster)
```

In one test they're almost equivalent, but still, iterator wins.

Comment: One more question. Does this mean `foreach` is a replacement for iterators? I mean, unless you only wanna grab 1 item, rather than going through the whole list, I don't see any reason for using an iterator.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using iterators at all. `foreach` is simply  for convenience, when you don't need to do anything except go through each element, reading them one by one, in order. I'm actually posting something more in my answer in a minute...

Comment: Okay thanks :) I don't like how you'd need a loop anyways to grab multiple elements using an Iterator. If some reason comes along where you need the `hasNext()` `next()` execution to be synchronized, but not the list. It can take up some space it doesn't need to. (not memory, but visually)

Comment: Exactly: Visually, not practically. I've updated my answer to compare the timing of foreach/iterator-access versus index-access.

Comment: I've made this into a blog post: aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/for_foreach

Comment: I don't get why your `testIterator` uses the classical for loop, whereas the `testFor` uses the iterator-ish `foreach` ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

For each was added at Java 5 for easier iteration over collections. However, it does not replace iterators as only with iterators you can modify the collection while iterating over it (via the iterator interface). Attempting to add\remove object from a collection within a for each will cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

If you're just reading values, foreach is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Java Language Spec 8(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf),14.14.2:

The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
    (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

So, for compiler that's the same.
Earlier versions of this standard contain the same description of 'foreach' statement

Answer (score 0):

Part of this has to do with the history of how java has developed over time.  Iterators were a language feature as a way to deal with collections of objects since Java 1.2.  Java 1.5 added the iterable interface and for-each loops.

Unless you need to do something specific with the iterator during your loop I would always use a for-each block ( which uses iterators in the implementation)

Answer (score -3):

Usually Iterator it's a bit speeder than to do a for loop using `objects.get(i)`, but the difference has no real impact on your code.
The main advantage of Iterator is that you can remove an object from the list during its crossing by calling the remove method on iterator.

Comment: Why would an iterator or foreach loop be faster or slower than the other? `for ( Object x : objects ) { ... }` is just `for ( Iterator i = objects.iterator() ; i.hasNext() ; ) { Object x = i.next(); ... }`.

Comment: Unless you mean a `for` loop with integer indices, and using `objects.get(i)`, because that _would_ be slower if you're using a List that has a `get` that's not constant time (e.g., a LinkedList).  That's not a foreach loop, though, which is what the OP was asking about.