# Iterating through a List using a while loop

Tags: java

I read [this blog post](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour) and proceeded to complete the questions to see if I could answer them in under an hour.

One of the simple challenges is to sum the values in a `List` using a `while` loop. Simple enough but food for thought.

I present two methods below, one using an incremented index and the other using an `Iterator`. Which solution is superior and why?

```
// Using an Iterator
public static int whileSummer(List<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        sum += iterator.next().intValue();
    }
    return sum;
}

// Using an incremented index
public static int whileSummer(List<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list.size()) {
        sum += list.get(i).intValue();
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My personal opinion is that the argument is merely down to LOC, readability and instantiation overhead. What do you think?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879255/performance-of-traditional-for-loop-vs-iterator-foreach-in-java DUPLICATE

Comment: A linked list in the second method would have some performance loss.

Comment: the superior solution is the one that will make your code more readable and scalable

Comment: For most instances I would believe that there is really no difference although I am sure one would be better at an extremely large number of elements. I don't know which one off hand.

Comment: One difference to note although a little off topic is that you cannot remove from the list using an iterator whereas you can with an index.

Comment: @Maxqueue - false.  You can use `iterator.remove()`.  Removing by index is actually bad as it can mess up your looping logic

Comment: yeah thanks stormhawke i was thinking of removing using for each loop.