# Improving list initialization for n-elements using nested lists

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I'd like to initialize a nested list without using a for-loop, the root list which is: cakeList will contain another ones eg.(100).

**My code:**

```
1. ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cakeList = new ArrayList<>();
2. for (int i=0;i<100;i++) cakeList.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

**I've tried:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cakeList = new ArrayList<>(100);
        cakeList.forEach(e-> new ArrayList<>());
        System.out.println(cakeList.size());
        cakeList.get(0);
    }
}
```

but as you maybe know, it complies, but throws an error al line #7 because cakeList is empty whe I try to cakeList.get(0).

*IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the 2nd method using lamda going to give IndexOutOfBoundsException as cakeList is empty initially. Are you facing any issues while trying the first method?

Comment: ```cakeList.forEach(e-> new ArrayList<>());``` this method yes throws me a exception because cakeList is empty.

Comment: @HeribertoHaydar, `cakeList.forEach` does NOT throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the `cakeList` is empty, just because there's no index here.  Please clarify your issue.

Comment: As Alex Rudenko said there is no exception, do you want to initialize your `cakeList` without using a for loop, for example with a `Stream` ?

Comment: @AlexRudenko I rewrite the code.. you're right the exception is throws because the list is empty.. no because ```` cakeList.forEach(e-> new ArrayList<>()); ``` this code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is convenient to use [`Stream::generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [`Stream::limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) to create predefined number of objects, so for the 2D list this would look as follows:

```java
List<ArrayList<Integer>> list2D = Stream.generate(ArrayList<Integer>::new)
        .limit(100) // Stream<ArrayList<Integer>>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

list2D.get(0).add(111); // 111 added to one entry
```

Also, `IntStream` with a fixed range may be used:

```java
List<ArrayList<Integer>> list2D = IntStream.range(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If it is important to have specific `ArrayList<ArrayList>` as a result, a collector `Collectors.toCollection` may be used:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list2D = IntStream.range(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

---

There is also a method [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) but it creates N copies of the same object which may have a side effect of applying a change in one element to all other "copy" elements in the list.

```java
List<ArrayList<Integer>> cakeList = Collections.nCopies(100, new ArrayList<>());
cakeList.get(0).add(111); // 111 is added to "all" entries in cakeList
```

Comment: Thank you, I use this:

````
        //Create Cakes
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1,N)
                .forEach(e->cakeList.add(new ArrayList<>()));

```

Comment: @HeribertoHaydar, if you use Stream API, there's no need to use `forEach` this way to modify an external object.  Create a stream of needed objects (here: empty `ArrayList<Integer>`) and collect them into `List` or other collection as shown in the update.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is fine, but post initialization, your lists are all empty, as you would expect [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (see Constructors) .

Per the methods section of the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html),

```
cakeList.get(0); // "Returns the element at the specified position in this list."
```

Since your list is empty, there is no element at the specified position.
The only way to create an ArrayList that is non-empty is to use the constructor (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) which takes in a Collection.
Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
numbers.get(0); //will return 1
```

Your goal of not wanting to use a for-loop for initialization is understandable, but see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879255/performance-of-traditional-for-loop-vs-iterator-foreach-in-java) for the speed comparison of the two methods. Note the method call

```
cakeList.forEach(e-> new ArrayList<>());
```

is equivalent to

```
Iterator<T> iter = cakeList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  iter.next().add(new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

A conclusion you will reach is that there is no shortcut to filling arrays, it will take O(n) where n is your array size.

Comment: Thank you! you're right .. I'm not worry about speed it's more for writing a ++readable code, reducing for-loops =).

I'm using this code:

`
        //Create Cakes
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1,N)
                .forEach(e->cakeList.add(new ArrayList<>()));

`