# Returning true if all objects in an ArrayList share a common value

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean

I have an ArrayList of objects, the object is an instruction class that has the following variables: toDelete, toUse, ID and executed. To have my program finish, I need to return true only when all members of the ArrayList's executed boolean return true.

```java
public boolean getComplete() {
    for (int i = 0; i < instructionArea.size(); i++) {
        if (instructionArea.get(i).getExecuted() == false) {
            instructionsCompleted = false;
            return instructionsCompleted;
        } else
            instructionsCompleted = true;
    }
    System.out.println(instructionsCompleted);
    return instructionsCompleted;
}
```

This is my work so far, but I know it is wrong, the program does not execute properly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Thank you responses, I actually realized I had some errors in my code elsewhere that was causing this to not work. Instructions were set to "executed" before they were supposed to. Oh well! Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the program does not execute properly"? Specifically, what behavior are seeing and how does that contrast with what you are hoping/expecting?

Comment: From a theoretical point, the algorithm looks correct on a glance (i.e. the method will return `true` iff. the method `getExecuted()` of all objects in `instructionArea` is returns `true` and `false` otherwise). I second @jhale1805's request for a [MRE].

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm looks fine, assuming that the variables `instructionArea` and `instructionsCompleted` are defined elsewhere and visible to this function. That said, here are two enhancements that may make the code easier to read (and therefore debug).

Note that I restructured the function to receive an `ArrayList` of `Booleans` as a parameter. In your case, you'd replace `Boolean` with your `Instruction` object and `bool` with `instruction.getExecuted()`

### For-each Loop

Since you are using an ArrayList, [it's a little more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879292/14765128) to use a for-each loop instead of indexing. Consider a function like the following.

```java
public boolean areAllTrue(ArrayList<Boolean> bools) {
    for (Boolean bool : bools) {
        if (!bool) return false;  // Return false if any element isn't true.
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Java's Streaming API

You can also one-line this function using [Java's Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams).

```java
public boolean areAllTrue(ArrayList<Boolean> bools) {
    return bools.stream().allMatch(bool -> bool == true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you do a reverse to save one more line :) Its stream API in the style like; "Is the any Match, that has not been executed)

```
public boolean getComplete() {
    return !instructionArea.stream().anyMatch(i -> !i.getExecuted());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean getComplete() {
    return instructionArea.stream().allMatch(InstructionArea::getExecuted);
}
```

Your logic may be expressed as *return `true` if all elements return `true` from `getExecuted()`* and this code reflects that exactly.

It also uses a [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (instead of a lambda), which IMHO makes for more elegant code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets inspect the problem:
You want to return true when **everything is true**.

You can invert that requirement:
Return false when **only one is false**.

By that logic, you can can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < instructionArea.size(); i++) {
        if(!instructionArea.get(i).getExecuted()) {
            return false; //when only one is false, it is not completed
        }
    }
return true; // we iterated over all elements and all were executed, hence it is completed
```